# Is every even cardinal number in a set with two binary operations a Boolean Algebra?

Tags: proof-verification, boolean-algebra

> True or false? Every natural and even number represents the cardinal of a set where two binary and closed operations are defined that give the whole the Boolean Algebra structure.

---

I know the following property of Boolean Algebras:

> If $A$ is a finite Boolean Algebra, then its cardinal is $|A|=2^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

But I don't know if the statement has the form of implication or if it is simply: $$\forall n(p(n)),\quad p(n)=\text{Cardinal of a set where}\\\text{two binary and closed operations}\\\text{are defined that give the set the Boolean Algebra structure}.$$ Anyway, if I take $n=6$ it is even but there is no natural $n$ such that $2^n=6$.

Is the counterexample correct or how is it?

Comment: There is certainly no Boolean algebra with 6 elements. I don't fully understand the phrasing of the question, but it seems to be false anyway, and your counterexample should be fine.

Comment: @amrsa thank you for your comment! Do you want to post it as an answer?